# How to check whether field exists or not in the firestore document?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Even though `if(doc.exists)` works perfectly, But if there is no data on a specific letter which i clicked, It does not show the console message - `console.log("There is a no song which starting with clickedletter");`

For example - If I clicked button "A" and imaging there is a song which starting letter "A". This data pop up quickly, But When I clicked button "T" which Data does not exist in the firestore document is not showing console message.

```
function getID(a){
    console.log("youclicked", a.id);
    var id = a.id;
    //getting this "a" value from an alphabetic pagination bar----------
    const clickedletter = a.getAttribute('value');
    var Aristid = sessionStorage.getItem("getArtistID");
    console.log("current artist ID "+ searchforid);

    db.collectionGroup('MP3_Songs').where("Idofartist", "==", Aristid).orderBy("Song_name").startAt(clickedletter).endAt(clickedletter +'\uf88ff').get().then((documentSnapshot) =>{
          documentSnapshot.forEach(doc=> {
            if(doc.exists){
               
               const data = doc.data();
              console.log("start with clickedletter", data);
              gotdata.innerText = "Song name: " + data.Song_name;
            } else{

             // this is the problem I got. This console log does not show if there is no data.---
                console.log("There is a no song which starting with clickedletter");
            }
      
            })
      
      
      
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a check to see if there are no documents in the entire result set, which is a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) type object.  It has a property called [empty](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#empty).

```
    db.collectionGroup('MP3_Songs').where("Idofartist", "==", Aristid).orderBy("Song_name").startAt(clickedletter).endAt(clickedletter +'\uf88ff').get()
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
            // here, there are no documents in the query results
        }
        else {
          // here, you can iterate the documents to find matches
          querySnapshot.forEach(documentSnapshot => { ... })
```

Comment: Mr. Stevenson, Thank you very much for your quick response and you are a lifesaver. It is working now as I wanted. Moreover, I have been watching cloud function videos on firecast Youtube who you presented and I learned a lot of things. again thank you!